# Why does React call my component more times than needed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have this simple example of a component that uses `useRef()` to count the number of times my component has rendered, and `useState()` to maintain some state:

```js
const {useState, useRef} = React;
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  const onClick = () => {
    setCounter(1);
  }
  renderCount.current++;
  alert("rendering"); // executes 3 times, not twice.
  return <div>
    <p>Render count: {renderCount.current}</p>
    <button onClick={onClick}>{counter}</button>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When I run the snippet above, the `alert` triggers and the ref counter is incremented due to the first render. When I click the button for the first time, `setCounter(1)` is called, which cuases the component to rerender/reexecute (as expected) causing the alert to appear for a second time and the ref counter to increase. When I click the button for the second time, `setCounter(1)` runs (which isn't updating the state since it is already `1`). As the state isn't changing, I would expect that there is no rerender needed and so my `App` component wouldn't be executed again. However, I instead see a third alert, indicating that the component was executed again, but the ref counter doesn't increase, nor does the rendered output change after the second click. Further clicks of the button show no alerts as expected. My question is why does React execute my App component again when the state doesn't change (ie: on the second click of the button)?

Answer (score 2):

This is rendering behavior of React for re-rendering and this is a special case. If you update the state to same value as the current state, then React re-render the component one more time and bail out from subsequent re-renders.

- The first render is the initial render and the **state** is 0
- The second render is for the state change **state** is 1
- The third render is for the special case ( this is not the initial render ) **state** is 1

However this unnecessary re-render is not the case for the initial render. I mean if you use `setCounter(0)` in the `onClick` method instead of `setCounter(1)`, then the component will be rendered only once even if `onClick` method is called subsequently.

The flow is like in the following diagram:

[image]

The reason is; React can’t guess the output of rendering won't change, it has to render one more time and compare the results with the previous render. But I am not sure how it is handled in the initial state (maybe a flag). There is not much information about it in the docs.

You might think that there is an efficiency problem but really there is not. There are two phases to the React rendering cycle: The **render phase** and the **commit phase**. DOM is updated after the commit phase and in this situation the process will not go to the commit phase and will **not** lead DOM update

Answer (score 1):

React docs states the concept of bailing for `useState` and `useReducer` hook:

> ##### Bailing out of a state update
>
> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out.

So in your case, since the `alert("rendering");` is in the component body, it's still being fired (once) while re-rendering.

> Further clicks of the button show no alerts as expected.

because after rendering phase, react compares the vdom (i.e. the reconciliation process) and bails out.

re-render steps:

- re runs the function component
- generates an vertual dom (i.e. the jsx => `react.createElement()` => js object)
- compares it
- bails out
- <s>commit</s>

**TL;DR:** after a re-render, if a `setState()` gets invoked with the same value as the rendered/current state, React will re-render that component once as a safety measure, compare it with previous render and if no difference are found react will bail out (meaning react will not re-render that component for the same `setState(value)` afterwards) without commiting any changes to actual dom

**Note:** after an initial render, if a `setState()` gets invoked with the same value as the rendered/current state, React direactly bails out without re-rendering that component.

Comment: Thanks, do you get why in the docs it says _Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out_? Why/When would it need to rerender the component again if the state didn't change? (ie: why does it even start rerendering and then only later check if the state changed to bail out or not during the rerender? Wouldn't it make more sense for react to first first check if the state has changed, then if it hasn't don't do anything?).

Comment: react doesn't just compares the state but also checks if it needs to bail out or not when states are equal. so if state === state it will check : if previous render was an `initial render` it will bail out  directly or if previous render was a `re-render` then react will re-render the component again, afterwards if no changes were found then bail out

Answer (score 0):

You are not using React's hook `useEffect()`, this is why your function, called anytime, calls it's local scoped functions. Think of your function component as of a letter. You pass it to the letterman closed and signed. But in your case, you passed it opened (during transfer it was read and called) but signed (it knows where it will be), hence you need to use hooks / lifecycle methods to control your React component.

That's why you are experiencing the alerts and incrementations.

If you have already worked with React class components, then you should know what's it lifecycle. If not, I encourage you to read this article: **[React Lifecycles](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)**.

**useEffect** has a behaviour of connection between `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount`. Anytime you update your state, or props, this method will be called and will execute given code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Maciej, but I'm not sure that this answers my question. My question is _why_ there is an additional alert() / execution of the App component function when the state isn't changing? I'm aware that I can use useEffect to control when alert is being executed (the alert is just there to show that the app is being reexecuted for a third time).

Comment: You are calling function that is in scope of the component, the component didn't rerender, but it called a function and itself. Rerendering it React means to update the document's tree, so the functions will be called, but it doesn't necessarly mean that returned value will be used by React to update the document's tree.