# New state is same as the previous one, nonetheless React re-renders the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I am currently experimenting around with React and can't understand one thing.

As you can see in the demo code below, when the third button is clicked, it changes the state `dummy` to `true` and thus causes a re-render of the `Demo` component. Now I've read in React docs, that if the new state value is the same as the previous one, no re-render is done.

```
function Demo()
{
   console.log('rendering')
   const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(false);

   return (
      <form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault();console.log('submitting')}}>
         <button>type="submit"</button>
         <button type="button">type="button"</button>
         <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => {setDummy(true)}}>type="submit" with state change</button>
         {dummy ? 'on' : 'off'}
      </form>
   )
}
```

After the first state update, I do expect the log `'rendering'` since the `dummy` state changes from `false` to `true` and thus causes `Demo` to re-render. But when I click the button the second time, I don't expect a re-render since the state `dummy` is changed from `true` to `true` (which isn't a change).

Nonetheless, somehow surprisingly, React re-renders the component this second time as well.

It's only from the third click, and beyond, that React doesn't re-render the `Demo` component.

Here's a live demo:

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/async-voice-xpompg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**Why is this behavior there?**

Comment: _"...changed from `false` to `false`"_, do you mean from `true` to `true`? Here is a question that is the same [Why does React call my component more times than needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68666070), not sure if the answers there provide a meaningful explanation to you though.

Comment: Yeah I meant `true` to `true`. Thanks for the correction.